# SQL Count query. Even numbers odd numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a product table, I need to know the number of records in the table. The Goal is to divide the return query into 2 separate query.

```
If (Count(*) % 2) = 0 return top(Count(*) / 2)
else return top((Count(*) / 2) + 1)
```

The main query is :

```
select coalesce(Price, ProductPrice) as Price, Product.ProductName, Customer.CustomerName, Product.CatalogNum from Product 
        inner join Customer on CustomerID = @custId
        left outer join CustomerPrice on dbo.Customer.CustomerID = dbo.CustomerPrice.CustomerID 
        and dbo.Product.ProductID = dbo.CustomerPrice.ProductID
        Where Product.ProductActive = 1 Order by Product.CatalogNum
```

Comment: If you just need the number of records in the table, you can do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM productTable`.  But I don't think i'm understanding your question...

Comment: So you want the top half of the table if the number of rows is even and the top half (rounding down) plus one row if the number of rows is odd; is that right? Which version of SQL server?

Comment: Daniel Renshaw - exactly my need. SQL Server express 2008 r2

Comment: select count(*) from <producttable> ?

Comment: what's with all the downvotes?  An OK question.

Comment: Probably because of the original question (it was kind of non-sensical before all the edits), but that's just a guess...

Comment: I liked it better before edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Count int
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable
SET @Count = CASE WHEN @Count % 2 = 0 THEN @Count / 2 ELSE @Count / 2 + 1 END
SELECT TOP(@Count) * FROM SomeTable ORDER BY SomeColumn
```

Note that there is a concurrency issue here - the number of rows might change between the first and second select statements, unless you apply a suitably restrictive locking hint/transaction isolation level.

Note also that an `ORDER BY` is essential to give any meaning to "top half".

[For information on the `TOP` clause.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx)

To get the bottom half do the same but subtract one if odd count and reverse the sort order a couple of times.

```
DECLARE @Count int
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM SomeTable
SET @Count = CASE WHEN @Count % 2 = 0 THEN @Count / 2 ELSE @Count / 2 - 1 END
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT TOP(@Count) * FROM SomeTable ORDER BY SomeColumn DESC) AS Data
ORDER BY SomeColumn
```

Comment: I dont need to worry about concurrency.

Comment: This is working great. how do I get the second half of the products??

Comment: Thank you. For some reason I couldn't sort the second half using the example you gave. the query manager wrote: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Order'. So I sorted the query in the report. everything is Great. 10x again

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the most optimal solution, but this might work for you:

```
DECLARE @Rows INT
SELECT @Rows = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) % 2 = 0 THEN COUNT(*)/ 2 ELSE COUNT(*) / 2 + 1 END FROM Table1
SET ROWCOUNT @Rows
SELECT * FROM Table1 
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: Does ROWCOUNT determine number of records to fetch or just tells you how many were fetched?

Comment: SET ROWCOUNT limits number of rows returned, while @@ROWCOUNT tells you how many were returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @a FLOAT
SET @a = (SELECT CEILING(COUNT(*)/2.0) FROM users)

SELECT TOP (CAST(@a AS INT)) * FROM users
```

Comment: Will SQL 2008 allow you to use a variable for TOP like that? I know SQL 2005 won't allow it. If so, that method is much better than my answer.

Comment: I tested in 2005.  You need to put it in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Select * From Table t
 Where (Select Count(*) From Table
        Where pkCol < t.PkCol) <=
       (Select Count(*)+1 From Table)/2
```

the integer division should deal with what you are rtying to do with the modulus operator...

to address the lack of understanding by the comment below,  if the table has an even number of records, say 20, then `count(*) = 20`, `Count(*) + 1 = 21`, and `(Count(*)+1) / 2 = 10`, the query will return all records where the count of records with a pk less than it's pk is less than or equal to 10, i.e. half the records.

If there are an odd number of records, say 21, then `count(*) = 21`, `Count(*) + 1 = 22`, and `(Count(*)+1) / 2 = 11`.  the query will return all records where the count of records with a pk less than it's pk is less than or equal to 11, i.e. half the records plus one, the same as the use of the modulus operator would do.

Comment: integer division is not going to help you here, I generally don't understand your answer.

Comment: @MK, If you don't understand integer division, then ....    2 / 2 = 1; 3/2 = 1; 4/2 = 2; 5/2 = 2;

Comment: Ah, I still do not understand your answer but the division part makes sense now.